# By mistake uninstalled PhpStorm IDE, Project files color changed

Tags: ide, phpstorm, settings

I am working on Laravel project and by mistake I've uninstalled PhpStorm. When I've reinstalled my IDE my project some files color changed.

I've search on google and it shows on PhpStrom site that red color means `During the last update, file was merged with conflicts` and blue means `File has changed since the last synchronization`

**My question is:** how to get rid these errors and work as normal? Can I continue with same problems means it will not effect my project.

[image]

Comment: So hat do you want to change? Those are just VCS file status. 1) If you want to change colors -- `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Colors & Fonts | File Status` and change to whatever you like. Thing is -- your color schema is meant to be used with light GUI Theme where those red/blue colors do look OK; but with Darcula (dark) GUI theme it does not work so well so you need to edit your Editor Schema colors. 2) If you want to get rid of those coloured statuses at all -- just disable VCS integration (git or whatever you have got there).

Comment: @LazyOne do you mean it doesn't create problems for me? but before uninstall all files are with normal color when I uninstall file color changed,why?

Comment: No idea what you have had there before. But those are just VCS file status colors -- they do not indicate actual errors. Few links to read: 1) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/file-status-highlights.html?search=file%20s 2) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Version+Control+Systems+Support+in+PhpStorm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually, I'm using git,whenever I add new files it(PHP storm) displays me different kind of colors but when I used version control commands(like `git add .`) then all files
color shows  normal color.
for different color details   https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/file-status-highlights.html?search=file%20s,plz visit this site.